# when i click on attachment button , it show me only the the title of alert dialog. So how to show the option in alert dialog

Tags: firebase, kotlin, android-alertdialog

This is a chat app, I want to display the options when a user click on attachment button and select one option like he want to send a picture or video or file documents to other user.[like this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVkDH.png)

But i am fail, when i click on attachment button it show me only the title of alert dialog.
[like this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohRIf.png)

It is my code of attachment button, there is some thing which i missed or ....

```
        attachment.setOnClickListener {
        val option: Charsequence = Charsequence("Images" , "Videos" , "File Documents")
        val itemList = arrayOf("Images","Videos","File Documents")
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@ChatLogActivity)
        val title = builder.setTitle("Select The File")
        builder.setItems( itemList.toString() ,
            onClickListener = DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialogInterface , i ->
                if (i == 0){
                    checker = "Images"
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                    intent.type = "image/*"
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"),438)
                }

                if (i == 1){
                    checker = "Videos"
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                    intent.type = "video/*"
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"),439)
                }

                if (i == 2){
                    checker = "File Documents"
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                    intent.type = "application/pdf"
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File Documents"),440)
                }
            })
        builder.show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set an array adapter like this.

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@ChatLogActivity)

val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this,
    android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice)
    arrayAdapter.add("Images")
    arrayAdapter.add("Videos")
    arrayAdapter.add("Documents")

builder.setTitle("Select One Option")

builder.setAdapter( arrayAdapter
    ) { _, i ->
        if (i == 0){
            checker = "Images"
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"),438)
        }

        if (i == 1){
            checker = "Videos"
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.type = "video/*"
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"),439)
        }

        if (i == 2){
            checker = "File Documents"
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.type = "application/pdf"
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File Documents"),440)
        }
    }
builder.show()
```

[image: view]

Comment: (context!!) give me an error [Unresolved reference:context]

Comment: @OsmanYousaf I have updated the answer, replace context with this.

Comment: Perfect sir , now it can work. Sir the radio option is seeming awkward, can we hide it.

Comment: Sir if we add some more options Audio, Location and Contact like whatsapp , can we arrange three option in a row and also add the icons.

Comment: Kindly accept it as an answer, and yes you can set a custom layout with it for more widgets.